# strripos Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 58887728 bytes)

Tags: php

Well I got this code:

```
function importXML($filename){
    if(file($filename)) $xml_file = file($filename);
    else umar(97);

    $content = substr($xml_file[1], strpos($xml_file[1], "<office:spreadsheet>"), strpos($xml_file[1], "</office:spreadsheet>") - strpos($xml_file[1], "<office:spreadsheet>"));
    $arr = array();
    $arr2 = array();
    $check = strripos($content, "</table:table-row>") + 18;
    $offset = 0;

    while($offset != $check){
        $start2 = strpos($content, "<table:table-row ", $offset);
        $end2 = strpos($content, "</table:table-row>", $offset);
        $offset = $end2 + 18;


        array_push($arr2, $start2, $end2);
        array_push($arr, substr($content, $start2, $end2-$start2));
    }

    return json_encode($arr);


}
```

And this line

```
$check = strripos($content, "</table:table-row>") + 18;
```

returns error

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 58887728 bytes)

I'm working with 58893135 bytes file.

In php.ini is set

> memory_limit=128M

So I'm wondering why I get this error, and how can I get rid of it.

Comment: Ever having to write a `while (true)`  line of code is a red flag.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to `while($offset != $check)`, and deleted if inside loop. Don't know why I did this that way, but main problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down a bit:

```
if(file($filename)) $xml_file = file($filename);
```

Here `$xml_file` will take 58MB . not to mention that you're reading the file twice. You should instead:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) $xml_file = file($filename);
```

Next bit:

```
$content = substr($xml_file[1], 
           strpos($xml_file[1], "<office:spreadsheet>"), 
           strpos($xml_file[1], "</office:spreadsheet>") - 
               strpos($xml_file[1], "<office:spreadsheet>")
         );
```

Here you're looking for `<office:spreadsheet>` twice in a large file, then storing the substring in `$content` which will also take about 58MB. You can at this point do : `$xml_file = null;` to remove references to it if you don't need it, i.e.

```
$spreadSheetStart = strpos($xml_file[1], "<office:spreadsheet>");
$spreadSheetLen = strpos($xml_file[1], "</office:spreadsheet>") - $spreadSheetStart;
$content = substr($xml_file[1], $spreadSheetStart, $spreadSheetLen);
$xml_file = null;
```

Now at the end you have an array of size approximately 58MB and you need to make it into a JSON of the same size while still having the `$content` in memory which will mean you need 170MB. You can again do:

```
$content = null; //unset($content); would also work. 
return json_encode($arr);
```

The main thing you need to understand about PHP and strings and array is that in PHP arrays and strings behave like primitive types which means they are always passed by value. Example:

```
$a = "Test"; 
$b = $a;
$b .= " again";
echo $a.PHP_EOL.$b.PHP_EOL;
```

This prints:

> Test
>
> Test again

This indicates that `$b` is a copy of `$a` and not a reference to the same memory location. A copy means that you've essentially doubled the memory requirements of the code by doing `$b = $a;`

The same goes for arrays and all other primitives (arrays, integers, booleans, floats).

Comment: Thanks, now almost everything works fine, but `return json_encode($arr);` is telling that Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31461376 bytes). setting `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` works, but as far as I see other responses it's not the best solution. So I'm confused is it better to split this array into two, and somehow send it separately, or  extend memory limit.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on what the memory complexity of `json_encode` is. If it's `2n` (i.e. twice the size of the input) then you've got no choice but to increase memory limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I increase memory limit i.e. to 256M, should I decrease it to default after the function is executed, or not?

Comment: @Straighter I think you should. Ideally your memory limit should be another means of debugging the code to ensure it's optimal. In this case for example there was a real need to increase it, but if you run out of memory in ordinary use cases which should not require more memory that would tell you there's bugs around.

Answer (score 1):

As apokryfos has mentioned in comment, we should NEVER use something like:

```
while(1)
```

or

```
while(true)
```

or

```
while(1===1)
```

or something like that.

Although if you must use it then in that case,
I believe what's happening is that your while loop somehow never coming to your break statement, that means your condition : `($offset == $check)` is never getting true.

As a verification, try starting a counter before while:
`$count = 1;`
increase it at the end of while and impose a condition of break when its lets say 50 :

```
while(true){
    //your code
    if($count === 50){
        break;
     }
     $count++;
}
```

Now if problem resolves then for sure its because of the fact that your `if` condition for breaking is never getting true..try thinking all aspects and add more conditions.

If that doesn't then I believe your app needs more memory than you are providing. Now I **HIGHLY DISCOURAGE** this method, but until you find real problem, you could add:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

at beginning of your code.

But I again mention, **THIS IS TEMPORARY**, problem exists in your code, increasing memory limit is not a solution but it will give you opportunity to locate the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ! You can add this line:

```
ini_set(”memory_limit","80M");
```

before

```
$check = strripos($content, "</table:table-row>") + 18;
```

Comment: WIth OPs current code 80 mb is too low. Minimum I would recommend is 200MB unless optimizations are made.